# what is the solution of AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer_create'?

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, cascade-classifier, lbph-algorithm

```
import cv2
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import mysql.connector

class Face_Recognition:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("1366x768+0+0")
        self.root.title("Face Recognition")

        self.img = Image.open("photos/pagebg.png")
        self.photoimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.label = Label(self.root, image=self.photoimg)
        self.label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        self.label.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_image)

    def resize_image(self, event):
        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height
        self.img = self.img.resize((new_width, new_height))
        self.photoimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.label.config(image=self.photoimg)

        self.button_frame = Frame(self.label, bg='white')
        self.button_frame.place(x=560, y=180, width=180, height=180)

        img02 = Image.open(r"E:\new project\photos\attandance.jpg")
        img02 = img02.resize((180, 180))
        self.photoimg02 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img02)

        b1 = Button(self.button_frame, image=self.photoimg02, border=0, cursor="hand2", command=self.face_function)
        b1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        self.button_frame = Frame(self.label, bg='black')
        self.button_frame.place(x=560, y=320, width=180, height=40)

        b1_1 = Button(self.button_frame, text="Attendance", border=0, command=self.face_function, cursor="hand2",
                      font=("Roca Two", 15, "bold"), bg="#D3D3D3", fg="black")
        b1_1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    def face_function(self) :
        def draw_boundary(img , classifier , scalefactor , minNeighbors , color , text , clf) :
            gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            features = classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_image , scalefactor , minNeighbors)

            for (x , y , w , h) in features :
                cv2.rectangle(img , (x , y) , (x + w , y + h) , (0 , 255 , 0) , 3)
                id , predict = clf.predict(gray_image [ y :y + h , x :x + w ])
                confidence = int((100 * (1 - predict / 300)))

                if confidence > 77 :
                    try :
                        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost" , user="root" , password="shihir09876" ,
                                                       database="student_info")
                        my_cursor = conn.cursor()
                        my_cursor.execute("SELECT `StudentName` FROM `student` WHERE `Student ID` = %s" , (id,))

                        result = my_cursor.fetchone()
                        if result :
                            StudentName , department = result
                            cv2.putText(img , f"Name: {StudentName}" , (x , y - 55) , cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX , 1 ,
                                        (255 , 255 , 255) , 3)
                            cv2.putText(img , f"ID: {id}" , (x , y - 40) , cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX , 1 ,
                                        (255 , 255 , 255) , 3)
                            cv2.putText(img , f"Department: {department}" , (x , y - 25) , cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX ,
                                        1 , (255 , 255 , 255) , 3)
                    except mysql.connector.Error as e :
                        print("Error while fetching data from MySQL" , e)
                    finally :
                        if conn.is_connected() :
                            my_cursor.close()
                            conn.close()
                else :
                    cv2.rectangle(img , (x , y) , (x + w , y + h) , (0 , 0 , 255) , 3)
                    cv2.putText(img , "Unknown" , (x , y - 25) , cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX , 1 , (255 , 255 , 255) , 3)

        def recognize(img , clf , face_cascade) :
            draw_boundary(img , face_cascade , 1.1 , 10 , (255 , 25 , 255) , "face" , clf)
            return img

        face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("data/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
        clf =cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
        clf.read("train_data.xml")

        video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while True :
            ret , img = video_cap.read()
            img = recognize(img , clf , face_cascade)
            cv2.imshow("Welcome To Face Recognition" , img)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13 :
                break

        video_cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = Face_Recognition(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

`

This is my code...I think that is 100% right ...But the error shows that

AttributeError: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'LBPHFaceRecognizer_create'

I already tried many ways from Google, YouTube, StackOverflow, etc. But nothing solves the error.

I change the Python version

pip install opencv-python

also

pip install opencv-contrib-python

I have done this many times but no solution

Comment: Does this help?  Does this help? `face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r"data/haarcascades/ ‘haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"`

Comment: Your code is working on my side. But i don't understand cannot read file on line 78..clf.read("train_data.xml")

Comment: Also I don't used SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The error means you're using the wrong method to create a **LBPH** face recognizer in OpenCV.

For OpenCV 4.x or later: `cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`
For OpenCV 3.x or earlier: `cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`

Check your OpenCV version with `cv2.__version__` and use the correct method accordingly.

Comment: I am using opencv version 4.9.0.80  & i am using cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() But still showing this error...

also showing this (Cannot find reference 'face' in '__init__.pyi')